# How to distinct between value types in transfer

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How does one distinct between sending different value types? 
E.g. between a transfer of ETH and a transfer of ERC20 token.
Extending the question, is it strictly necessary for an external contract such as an escrow, to be approved, to transfer any ERC20 on behalf of one of the contracts?

Is it possible to do:

**contract A)** sends ETH -> **Escrow** <- **contract B)** sends ERC20

Escrow swaps between the two without approval?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's pretty much possible. That is how ICO's work. You send `ETH`, then they send you `ERC20 tokens`,

> **address A** ----sends ETH---> **Issuance contarct** ---sends Token ---> **address A**

You can chnage this dynamics by replacing first address A with contract A and then last address A with contract C.

Comment: how does issuance contract know which token to send if it has multiple erc20 tokens? and does one have to send tokens to it in advance of allowing people to send eth to it?